# Excel: Display two currencies on graph axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I am trying to display two currencies on the y-axis. I do not want two y-axis. Essentially, I am presenting to two audiences; some from South Africa (hence Rand), and some from the Netherlands (hence Euro). So I want the y-axis to display rand and euro (see the graph below).

[Line chart displaying two currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAgLl.png)

I do not want to include two different bars, as is displayed in the above graph. I want to take the figures on the y-axis and convert them into Euros (at a specified exchange), displaying both sets of figures. Then the audience will be able to see how much ZAR and how much Euro each of the bars represent.

I look forward to your answers.

Thanks,

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this one will help you to customize two Currency on Axis:**

[image]

*This you need to write in Format Code Text box while formatting the Axis.*

```
 [>999999] #,,$;#,"Eu",$
```

**Or**

*Use this Custom Format for Values on other Axis.*

```
"Ran/Eu",#,##0 will look like Ran/Eu,350.
```

**Note:**

- Alter the Currency symbol with other as your need.

Comment: Glad to help you @Surfer keep asking, ☺

Answer (score 0):

in case you use microsoft excel,
you can make it with "combo" chart, find it in "all chart",

X label   |   dolar currency   |   another currency
income    |   10000            |   100

if you have table like example above, just block all, enter chart option, choose combo, and choose format with 2 axis.